# zap (docker) api scan against graphql specifying include or exclude queries

Tags: graphql, zap, zap-api-scan

Thank you in advance for your time on this.

Is there a way to tell zap api scan, using `docker run -i owasp/zap2docker-stable zap-api-scan.py`, what queries and/or mutations from my graphql schema to hit during scan and which to exclude from the scan or do I need to set up my schema file to only include what I want scanned?

My problem is that the schema I am trying to scan is massive. I only want to scan like 15 mutations out of about 200...

Something like:

```
docker run -i owasp/zap2docker-stable zap-api-scan.py \
  -t https://mytarget.com -f graphql \
  -f graphql \
  -schema schema-file.graphql \
  --include-mutations file-with-list-of-mutations-to-include
```

Answer (score 0):

The packaged scans are quite flexible, and do allow you to specify exactly which scan rules to run and which 'strength' to use for each rule.
However there are limits to what you can easily acheive, so you might want to look at the [Automation Framework](https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/automate/automation-framework/) which is much more flexible.